# loc statement returns series and I need a single value

Tags: python-3.x

I use the loc statement to look up each value of a coordinate pair but apparently, if you use loc with a condition it returns a series and not a single value. My conditions make that I should always get only one value back but when I assign it to its field I always end up in the 'except' part of my statement. How can I make this work ?

My situation is as follows: I have a dataframe containing a sequence of possession points (defined by x,y coordinates). For each line I have the following fields:

```
Possession | PossessionSequence | x_from | y_from
-----------+--------------------+--------+-------
     1                 1            12       24
     1                 2            89       45
     1                 3            67       80
     1                 4            110      72
     2                 1            23       79
     2                 2            32       93
```

Now, I want to add x_to and y_to fields to this dataframe where the values for these fields in the first records are the x_from and y_from from the second record. The x_to and y_to for the second record are the x_from and y_from from the third record and so on. So within a possession, I always need to take the values from the next possessionsequence. So I would like to get the following:

```
Possession | PossessionSequence | x_from | y_from | x_to | y_to
-----------+--------------------+--------+--------+------+------
     1                 1            12       24      89     45
     1                 2            89       45      67     80
     1                 3            67       80      110    72
     1                 4            110      72
     2                 1            23       79      23     79
     2                 2            32       93
```

Now when I get to the last value of the possessionsequence (e.g. 4 for possession 1 in the dataframe above) there is no next record (and as shown the x_to and y_to values should be left blank) and I therefor wrapped the lines in a try ... except statement so that when no next line is found blanks are assigned instead.

So far I have come up with the following code:

```
# Add the TO x,y coordinates to each line (except the last one)
df['X_to'] = 0
df['Y_to'] = 0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
  current_team = df.loc[index, 'Team']
  current_posession = df.loc[index, 'Posession']
  current_sequence = df.loc[index, 'PosSeq']
 
  try:
    df.loc[index, 'X_to'] = df.loc[(df['Team'] == current_team) & (df['Posession'] == current_posession) & (df['PosSeq'] == current_sequence + 1), 'X_from']
    df.loc[index, 'Y_to'] = df.loc[(df['Team'] == current_team) & (df['Posession'] == current_posession) & (df['PosSeq'] == current_sequence + 1), 'Y_from']
  except:
    df.loc[index, 'X_to'] = ""
    df.loc[index, 'Y_to'] = ""
```

But when I run this it always ends up in the 'except' part and no 'to' coordinates are assigned. I am trying to familiarize myself with the debug mode in Visual Studio code and there I see that the loc statement to look up the 'to' coordinates comes up with the correct value, but only as part of a series with the first element the current iteration in the for loop. How can I extract only the coordinate value from this ? All help is welcome !!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bother ... it was as simple as adding .values[0] to the lines in question (and defining the columns upfront with the correct datatype).